# limit comparison test on a general series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was given this sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \sin(1/n)$, I need to determine it's convergence, First of all $$\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} \rightarrow1$$ therefore the series diverges with $1/n$, then it seems to me that because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n/n$ converges, and $\frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n} \rightarrow1$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \sin(1/n)$, converges but the limit comparison test only works on a positive series. 
Can I conclude that the series converges because of this?

Comment: Look at [Alternating Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: Thanks, when I looked at the Alternating Series at the start I accidentally derived $\sin(1/(x+1))/\sin(1/x)$ instead of $\sin(1/x)$ to show it's decreasing.

Comment: The series is not only alternating, the summands form a decreasing sequence in absolute values tending to $0$. This is enough to conclude that it must converge.